# How to get the normal value after the multiplication of two big float values which results in exponential value in ruby language?

Tags: ruby

> I am taking input string from the user:

```
 puts(" Input Data (Sample Input: 555555*555555)")
    input = gets.chomp
```

> Next, I am splitting the input with a symbol '*'

```
if input.include? "*"
        $operator = "*"
        values = input.split("*")
        puts(" Value: ", values)
      end
```

> Next, I am converting the two numbers to float data type

```
  $value1 = values[0].to_f
  $value2 = values[1].to_f
```

Then, I am multiplying these two numbers

```
def multiply(value1, value2)
    result = $value1 * $value2
    puts(" Multiplication Result: ", result)
  end
```

> Input and Output Sample:

```
>  Sample Input:  6415613213131*31564646546
>  Sample Output: Multiplication Result: 2.0250656344832737e+23
```

Comment: `puts format('Multiplication result: %f', result)` maybe? Keep in mind that many numbers can't be represented exactly using floats.

Comment: @Stefan You made my day. Bundle of thanks. It worked

Comment: @Stefan Please put it in the answer box. I want to vote for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`format`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#format-method) to specify formatting, e.g.:

```
  f   | Convert floating point argument as [-]ddd.dddddd,
      | where the precision specifies the number of digits after
      | the decimal point.
```

Example:

```rb
result = 6415613213131.0 * 31564646546.0
#=> 2.0250656344832737e+23

puts format('Multiplication result: %f', result)
# Multiplication result: 202506563448327368605696.000000
```

**But:** you have to keep in mind that many floats are approximations of the decimal numbers they represent and therefore inaccurate. For example, the above multiplication result is not correct:

```
 6415613213131   * 31564646546         #=> 202506563448327380995526 <- correct
(6415613213131.0 * 31564646546.0).to_i #=> 202506563448327368605696 <- incorrect
                                       #                   ^^^^^^^^
```

If you want precise results, it might be a better idea to use [`BigDecimal`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) which handles large decimal numbers just fine:

```rb
require 'bigdecimal'

a = BigDecimal('6415613213131')
b = BigDecimal('31564646546')

result = a * b
#=> 0.202506563448327380995526e24
```

Its [`to_s`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#to_s-method) method even comes with basic formatting:

```rb
puts "Multiplication result: #{result.to_s('F')}"
# Multiplication result: 202506563448327380995526.0
```